# Lista sem o número negativo

Tags: python, lista, algoritmo

O exercício é o seguinte: um programa que leia os valores e separe-os numa lista de pares ou ímpares. A contagem só para quando vier um número negativo (que não deve estar na lista). Eu já fiz o programa e ele funciona só que eu não consigo fazer com que o número negativo fique fora da lista. Meu código tá assim:

```
numero = [[], []]  
valor = 1  
while valor >= 0:  
    valor = int(input('Número: '))  
    if valor % 2 == 0:  
        numero[0].append(valor)  
    else:  
        numero[1].append(valor)  
print(f"{numero[0]}\n"  
      f"{numero[1]}")
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Não precisa criar a variável fora do `while` com um valor artificial só para que entre nele. Você pode fazer assim:

```
numero = [[], []]  
while True:
    valor = int(input('Número: '))  
    if valor < 0: # número negativo
        break # sai do hile
    if valor % 2 == 0:
        numero[0].append(valor)  
    else:  
        numero[1].append(valor)  

print(f"{numero[0]}\n{numero[1]}")
```

`while True` cria um *loop* infinito - na verdade, ele se repete até que seja interrompido por um [`break`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#break). E o `break`, neste caso, é chamado se o valor for negativo, que é a sua condição de saída. Assim, ele sai do `while` antes de inserir o número negativo em uma das listas, que é o que você precisa.

---

Como o programa só vai inserir números positivos e o resto da divisão por 2 será zero ou 1, você também poderia usar o próprio resto como o índice:

```
numero = [[], []]  
while True:
    valor = int(input('Número: '))  
    if valor < 0: # número negativo
        break # sai do hile
    numero[valor % 2].append(valor)
```

---

A [outra resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/475226/112052) também funciona, mas tem um porém: a condição para o número ser válido e inserido nas listas (`numero >= 0`) se repete 3 vezes no código. E se você precisar mudar essa condição (por exemplo, se o programa agora pode aceitar números negativos, e os positivos só podem ser menores que 100, ou qualquer outro critério que seja), terá que fazê-lo nesses 3 lugares. Já usando o código acima, a condição fica em um único ponto e basta mudar ali, caso precise.

Apesar de ser só um exercício, já é importante ir pensando nestes aspectos, pois evitar esse tipo de repetição ajuda muito na manutenção do código - esse princípio é conhecido como [DRY (Don't Repeat Yourself)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself).

Answer (score 3):

Uma outra maneira de conseguir fazer isso é adicionar uma verificação no `if`: `...and valor >= 0:`

Assim evitaria que um *valor* menor que 0 entrasse.

Código:

```py
numero = [[], []]  
valor = 1  
while valor >= 0:  
    valor = int(input('Número: '))  
    if valor % 2 == 0 and valor >= 0:  
        numero[0].append(valor)  
    elif valor % 2 != 0 and valor >= 0:  
        numero[1].append(valor)  
print(f"{numero[0]}\n"  
      f"{numero[1]}")
```

Comment: Entendi, obrigado. O problema era realmente simples.

Answer (score 1):

Se você estiver utilizando o **Python 3.8** ou superior, podes utilizar **[Assignment Expressions](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.8.html#assignment-expressions)** para montar o seu código. Desta forma o código ficaria:

```
numero = [[], []]
while (n := int(input('Valor: '))) > -1:
    if n % 2 == 0:
        numero[0].append(n)
    else:
        numero[1].append(n)

print(f'Números pares: {numero[0]}')
print(f'Números ímpares: {numero[1]}')
```

**Como funciona este código?**

O bloco **while** capturará cada valor digitado desde que sejam valores positivos. Em seguida o bloco **if** avaliará se o referido valor digitado é par. Caso positivo, o valor será armazenado em **numero[0]** - números pares - e, caso contrário, o valor será armazenado em **numero[1](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.8.html#assignment-expressions)** - números ímpares.

Caso, algum valor inserido seja **menor que zero** - valor negativo - o bloco while encerra sua execução desconsiderando o último valor digitado.

Em seguida, serão exibidas as duas listas. Uma contendo os valores pares e a outra contendo os números ímpares.